# Javascript this keyword within object

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have this object:

```
var eventDisplay = {
  eventTable: $('.table-event > table'),
  archiveButton: $('table-event__archive-button'),
  deleteButton: $('table-event__delete-button'),
  checkedCheckboxes: $('.table-event input[type=checkbox]'),
  countChecked: function() {
    return this.checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
  },
  selectionChanged: function() {
    if (this.countChecked() > 0) {
      deleteButton.removeClass("disabled");
      archiveButton.removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      deleteButton.addClass("disabled");
      archiveButton.addClass("disabled");
    }
  },
  attachCheckboxHandler: function() {
    this.checkboxes.on('click', this.selectionChanged);
  }
}
```

When I call `eventDisplay.attachCheckboxHandler()`, the `this` in attachCheckboxHandler is refering to the object as I expected. However, as it calls `selectionChanged`, `this` refers to the checkbox instead. But I want `this` within the selectionChanged to refer to `eventDisplay`. Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `this` keyword in an event function relates to the caller of the function, not necessarily the overall instance (as you discovered).

For example, the event might be triggered like the following:

```
// checkbox has been selected
checkbox.selectionChanged.call();
```

So then in your callback, `this` will be the checkbox instance.

Since you are assigning the main object to a variable, you should just be able to reference that in your callback:

```
var eventDisplay = {
  selectionChanged: function() {
    if (eventDisplay.countChecked() > 0) { <-- note here
      deleteButton.removeClass("disabled");
      archiveButton.removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      deleteButton.addClass("disabled");
      archiveButton.addClass("disabled");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The context (`this`) is changed under very specific circumstances; normally, when you invoke a method (function that is set as an object property) using the dot notation. For example, `foo.bar()` will set `this` to `foo`.

If you don't call a function using the dot notation, you typically do not change the context. For example, `baz = foo.bar; baz()` looks equivalent to the above, but will not set `this` to `foo` (it will leave it unchanged).

The exact same thing is happening in your code, but instead of a local variable assignment, you have a parameter passing: `function quux(baz) { baz(); }; quux(foo.bar)` assigns `foo.bar` to `baz`, just like above.

What you can do is bind a new context to a function: `baz = foo.bar.bind(foo); baz()` will set the context to `foo` every time `baz` is invoked. Alternately, and equivalently, you can bind `baz` to a wrapper function that will invoke `foo.bar()` properly: `baz = function() { foo.bar(); }; baz();`.

How this translates to your example:

```
this.checkboxes.on('click', this.selectionChanged.bind(this));
```

(For completeness' sake, besides method calling and bound function calling, the context is also set when `new` operator is used, and with `call` and `apply` functions)

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to declare your object as a function and create an alias for it (I use thiz), which you use on your methods. Finally you return the actual object where you expat only the functions you want. Now all the thiz refer to the same object.

```
var myObj = function() {
    var thiz = this;
    var method1 = function (args) {
        // use thiz here
    }
    // define more methods of you want, such as method2...

    return {
        method : method1,
        anotherMethod : method2
    };
}
```